# loop to minus 15 days from the current date

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to call an exe that requires a date range parameter (ex: 20130801-20130815) and then loop it so it minuses 15 days and calls the exe with the new date range.

I thought of using a do until but i'm not sure how (new to powershell/programming) but I'm sure this is far from the right method :). I've just started to figure this out, so thanks in advance for any/all help.

```
do {

    $startDate = (Get-Date).adddays(-34)
    $requireddate = some date that is set ad-hoc
    $startdate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")

    #[datetime]::parseexact($startdate,"MMddyyyy",$null)

    Call THE EXE at this point with the parameters $startdate and $enddate

    $enddate = $startdate.AddDays(-15) 

    write-host $enddate.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    }
until ($enddate -eq $requireddate)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a For loop to do what you're trying to achieve as well:

(I've split things out into Variables a bit as well as I find it helps when writing functions)

```
$requiredAddDays = 30
$requiredDate = (get-date).AddDays($requiredAddDays)
$startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-34)
$endAddDays = -15


for($i = $startDate; $i -lt $requiredDate; $i = $i.AddDays(1))
{

    Write-Output "$($i.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))-$($i.AddDays($endAddDays).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))"

}
```

Using `Write-Output` means that whatever is returned is returned as an object (whereas `Write-Host` always returns a string).  By returning an object it can be fed into the Pipeline (using the pipe `|`)

The $(`code`) syntax in my `Write-Output` means that whatever is inside of the brackets gets evaluated before returning the string (as an object).

You could go one further and make this a parameterised function if you'll be using it lots:

```
Function Get-DateRange
{
Param(
[datetime]$startDate,
[int]$endAddDays,
[datetime]$requiredDate
)

    for($i = $startDate; $i -lt $requiredDate; $i = $i.AddDays(1))
    {

        Write-Output "$($i.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))-$($i.AddDays($endAddDays).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))"

    }

}
```

Then you could call it (once it's loaded into your session) by running something like this:

```
Get-DateRange -startDate (get-Date).AddDays(-10) -endAddDays 15 -requiredDate (get-Date).AddDays(15)
```

P.S. If you would like to write functions it might be a good idea to try and keep to the typical Powershell Verbs if you can.  Run `get-verb | sort verb` to see the whole list. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways.  If you want to use a Powershell specific method (not do..until or while(){} ) then you could go with a pipeline:

```
0..15 | %{
  $changingDate = $startdate.AddDays(-$_)
  #do your work with the .exe & $changingDate
  $changingDate
}
```